# What's the difference between 1/1/1970 and 12/31/1969 UNIX epoch invalid dates?

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

I know that when there's an invalid UNIX date, the default time is Epoch, but I see that some servers' default is 12/31/1969 while others servers' default is 1/1/1970. What's the difference between these two?

Comment: Perhaps it's due to the server's time zone?

Comment: timestamp(1969-12-31 23:59:59) == -1  :P

Comment: @Cuberto probably, but I hope someone could clarify this.

Comment: Add some code to your question to actually demonstrate this. There's more than one possible explanation.

Comment: @Bouchard The Unix epoch is defined as 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC. In GMT-8 time zone, this would be 12/31/1969 4:00:00 PM. From the information you provided, this is the best explanation I can give.

Comment: @Evert: I don't have any code because this is a problem I spot occasionally, for example, on Twitter.

Comment: @Cuberto, make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the server's time zone. For example, the Unix epoch is defined as 1/1/1970 00:00:00 UTC. In GMT-8 time zone, this would be 12/31/1969 4:00:00 PM.